# creating a fraction or decimal using only addition or subtraction

Tags: fractions, decimal-expansion

how do i create a decimal or a fraction by only using addition or subtract? I have the numbers 1 and 2, and I want to end up with .5 -- have been stuck on this for quite a bit! I cannot just do 1/2, I have to somehow use only addition or subtraction.

```
var divide = function(x, y) {
    //the number of times you need to subtract y from x.

  if (y === 0) {
    return 0
  } 
  // if 
  if (x - y === 0) {
    return 1;
  } 
  if (x < y) {
    return 0; <--- this is where the problem is 
  } else {
    return (1 + divide(x - y, y)); // need to get this toFixed somehow.  
  }

};
```

Comment: I think it cannot be done - the integers are closed under addition and subtraction. It could be a sort of joke , $1 = 1.0$ and $1+2+2=5$ so put the decimal point and the 5 together

Comment: As other people have said, It is not possible to add/subtract mathematical integers and end with a non-integer. Your program isn't particularly clear, but you can obviously divide or very likely use bit-wise addition to obtain your result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're restricted to integers, then you can't.

The integers are closed under addition.  (In other words, adding two integers gives you another integer.)  Same for subtraction.

Comment: hmmm interesting. what if I was not restricted to integers and I could change types? I'm sure I could convert the numbers to strings in javascript

Comment: I was referring to integer in the mathematics sense, not the data type sense.  (This being math.SE and all ...)  I guess then, *how* are you creating them?  Writing a program?  Or with a mathematical equation?

Comment: In JavaScript, i'll update to include my program.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to decide whether you want your answer as a fraction with denominator as a power of 2 or as a decimal (a fraction with denominator as a power of 10).

Let's suppose you are going to go for the fraction with denominator as a power of 2 and that you have decided that you are happy to work to the nearest $\frac 1 {16}$.

To demonstrate, I will give the example of 5 divided by 7: a half is too easy!

Start by adding 5 to 5 - gives you 10.

Then add 10 to 10 - gives you 20.

Then add 20 to 20 - gives you 40.

Then add 40 to 40 - gives you 80.

We do this adding four times because $16=2^4$. For greater accuracy we would add more times.

Now subtract 7 repeatedly and increment your counter as you go.

You can subtract 11 times until you reach a value less than 7.

Stop.

Your answer is $\frac 57 \approx \frac {11}{16}$